# How to tell if Outlook 2007 will send the email with encryption

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, encryption

Can't seem to find this info anywhere, maybe not possible?  With Outlook 2007, how can I tell if the email is going to be sent with encryption?  I know how to select the deeply-buried checkbox that selects encryption.  There doesn't appear to be any visual indication anywhere on the Message edit dialog.

Specifically, if someone emails me with an encrypted email, will my response also be encrypted by default?  (Doesn't look like, judging from the deeply-buried security settings dialog, I have to explicitly go in and select encryption).

**EDIT:** Solved now, thanks Dennis.  I had to add/delete/re-add the encrypt button a bunch of times, before Outlook decided to enable the button (was showing disabled).  Or maybe it was the action of sending myself an encrypted email, whatever, the button is now added (and enabled) to the Quick Access Toolbar.  Also, this button now shows up in the Options area in the ribbon as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specifically, if someone emails me with an encrypted email, will my response also be encrypted by default?

No. Whether outgoing messages will be encrypted or not depends on your settings, not the message you're replying to.

To encrypt outgoing messages **by default**, go to

```
Tools -> Trust Center -> E-mail Security -> Encrypted e-mail
```

and activate the following checkbox:

```
Encrypt contents and attachments for outgoing messages
```

---

> I know how to select the deeply-buried checkbox that selects encryption. There doesn't appear to be any visual indication anywhere on the Message edit dialog.

To make the option visible and easily accessible, follow these steps<sup>1</sup>:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to compose a new message.
2. Right-click the Office icon in the upper left corner.
3. Choose `Customize`.
4. In the drop-down menu, choose `Message`.
5. In the left column, choose `Encrypt`.
6. Click `Add >>`.

---

<sup>1</sup> This might get messy, since I'm translating from Spanish.

Comment: If somebody with an English copy of Outlook 2007 could improve the second part of my answer, I'd be grateful.